# Spotlight Creating Shadow Artifacts

Tags: scenekit

I'm getting strange shadow artifacts when using spotlights in my scene. For materials I used physicallyBased. Here's a screenshot below of the shadow artifacts.

[image: SCNShadowMode = .forward]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution was to change the light property SCNShadowMode from the default ".forward" setting to ".deffered".

[image]